# Why does the app crash every time i press start game?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to move an object across the screen when a button is pressed. I can't really tell what is wrong with the code. Every time I press start game the app crashes and the console says `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`. Also I have 2 warnings but don't know how to fix them.

The code is here:

```
-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender{
    startGame.hidden = YES;

    shipMovingLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.07 target:self selector:@selector(leftTap) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    shipMovingRight = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.07 target:self  selector:@selector(rightTap) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)leftTap:(id)sender{
   ship.center = CGPointMake(ship.center.x -1, ship.center.y);


}

-(void)rightTap:(id)sender{
    ship.center = CGPointMake(ship.center.x -1, ship.center.y);
}
```

The warnings that I am getting are undeclared selector 'left tap' and undeclared selector 'right tap'.

Comment: FYI - When you post an error message in a question, please post the actual and exact error message, not a rough approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your timer code to the following:

```
shipMovingLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.07 target:self selector:@selector(leftTap:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

shipMovingRight = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.07 target:self  selector:@selector(rightTap:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

You need to include the colons to indicate that their is single parameter for that selector, in this case it is the `(id)sender`. If there were two parameters, you would use `@selector(rightTap::)`, etc.

For your information, the undeclared selector message is actually a warning, not an error (unless you've enabled treat warnings as errors), this should have provided a clue that there was something wrong with the selector you provided.